# The output of a boost converter doesn't stay at 5 V

Tags: raspberry-pi, ups, supercapacitor, buck-boost

Let me start by apologizing for my english in advance :)

I'm trying to build an UPS for my raspberry Pi (even though I have basically zero experience in electronics). When the power cuts out, I want the Pi to stay ON for another 10-15 seconds. After doing a little research on google, I've decided to buy some supercapacitors and one of these neat boost converters - https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00HV59922. I set the output of the converter to 5 V, then Ive added two supercaps(5.5 V 4 F) to the input of the converter and finally powered the whole circuit with a 5 V powerbank. Then I measured both the input and the output of the converter to see if it works as expected.. and it didn't.

When the input voltage was between 3,6 ~ 5 V, the output was steady at 5 V. At 3.5 V, the output jumped to 12 V(?).. then it kept falling, at 3 V on the input the output was 7 V.. the output got back to 5 V when the input was approx. 2.75 V.

I was hoping to get either 5 V, or nothing. Can someone please explain what could be wrong here?

Comment: Most boost converters require a minimum load to maintain regulation. What kind of load were you using to make your measurements?

Answer (score 1):

The XL6009 IC that is used on that DC/DC converter board does not work with input voltages below 5V.

See the [datasheet](https://www.sunrom.com/get/283300) for reference.

Comment: You are 100% correct, the vendor claimed it can handle outputs from 3V.. nevermind. From now on I ll be more carefull. 

I ll try one of these (http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1500000-1599999/001516578-da-01-en-5V_USB_BOOST_1000MA_VON_1_8V_2030_ADA.pdf). Input ranges from 1.8 to 5.5V, which is exactly what I need

Comment: now my only concern is - will the output voltage remain the same even when the input drops?

Comment: Sure it will, as long as the input voltage is within the operation range of the controller. I don't know if there is any cheap board available with that IC, but there is some boards on ebay build on the MT3608, which seems pretty cheap. It works from 2V+. Try searching for that part directly, or just "2V boost converter" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Putting capacitors between the battery and the converter won't do you any good. Capacitors will provide additional current if the voltage changes suddenly, but the battery voltage changes slowly. The capacitors must be between the converter and the Raspberry pi, and you must add an isolation diode or other circuitry to make sure that the capacitors don't discharge back through the converter when the converter voltage falls.

It's hard to tell if you have chosen the correct capacitors. We need more information about how much current your Raspberry pi requires. You should also provide a link to the datasheet for the capacitor.

Your link for the converter is to a vendor website in German. We need a manufacturer's data sheet in English, please. However, if the input voltage to the converter falls below its recommended operating range then you can't make any assumptions about how the converter will behave. In particular, you can't assume that the output voltage will stay at 5V until it finally drops to zero. If you operate the converter outside of its recommended range then anything can happen.

Comment: "The capacitors must be between the converter and the Raspberry pi" - why would I need a converter then? The powerbank already gives me steady 5V and im pretty sure it already has a diode somewhere in its circuitry, so the capacitors can only discharge one way. The Pi draws 600-650 mA, I dont know if 8 farads will be enough, but im not worried about that, I can add more caps if needed.

Comment: OK, now I see what you are trying to do. You said "when the power cuts out" but it wasn't clear what you meant by that.